# Leading Zeros for Variable Length Field

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form that asks the user to enter some information into text boxes, then some VBA code that manipulates those values and enters them into a table.

One of these text boxes asks for a numeric serial number.  This serial number value could be four or five digits in length, and it may contain one or more leading zero(s). e.g. `0001` or `00758` or `0463`.

Once the VBA code enters this value into the table, it loops through it, increments it, and makes another entry.  This repeats until all the serial numbers are added to the table.  I have the serial number value taken from the text box declared as a string in my code, but it still drops my leading zeros.

Comment: show your code. And what is your question again?

Comment: Sounds like either the variable you're using to store the serial number, or the field in the table, is a numeric type, not a character type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar problems, using CStr() to force a string fixed it for me. So, something like:  sMyString = CStr(vUserValue) instead of sMyString = vUserValue.

Also, you might be dropping the zeros when you increment the number. You can re-add them with something like: sMyString = String(5-len(sMyString),"0") & sMyString where 5 is the original number of digits.

```html
sMyString = String(5-len(sMyString),"0") & sMyString
```